# How to get the empty values in data using awk command

Tags: awk, sed

I had linux lvs command sample result set. I am trying to re-arrange the fields using AWK command.Using that I am not able to skip the empty vales in data.

```
LV    VG      Attr        LSize   Pool  Origin  Data%  Meta%  Move  Log
root  centos  -wi-ao----  45.62g        root                        Online
swap  centos  -wi-ao----                root                        Offline
```

I tried the following command,

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10}' lvs.txt
```

But Output is

```
LV VG Attr LSize Pool Origin Data% Meta% Move Log
root centos -wi-ao---- 45.62g root Online
swap centos -wi-ao---- root   Offline
```

My expected result must be,

```
LV   | VG     | Attr       | LSize  | Pool | Origin | Data% | Meta% | Move | Log
root | centos | -wi-ao---- | 45.62g |      | root   |       |       |      | Online
swap | centos | -wi-ao---- |        |      | root   |       |       |      | Offline
```

Please help me through this.
Any other possible ways is also welcome.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solution, use `awk` with `--separator` and format the output with `awk -F` (Field Separator) and `printf`:

```
lvs --separator ',' | awk -F ',' '{printf "%-15s| %-10s| %10s| %10s| %10s| %10s| %10s| %10s| %10s|%10s|  \n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10}'
```

Output:

```
  LV           | VG        |       Attr|      LSize|       Pool|     Origin|      Data%|      Meta%|       Move|       Log|  
  logicalTest1 | testgroup | -wi-a-----|      1.00g|           |           |           |           |           |          |  
  logicalTest2 | testgroup | -wi-a-----|      1.00g|           |           |           |           |           |          |
```

> **Explanation**

Installed lvm and created a couple of lvs to test.

The lvs command produces an output without field separators, just a bunch of spaces. After redirecting the output to a file I've proceeded to [display the spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688623/how-to-display-spaces-and-tabs-using-unix-and-the-cat-command):

```
 root@florida:~# cat test2 | tr " " "*"
**Host*******Attr*******KMaj*LSize*OSize*Origin
**florida****-wi-a-----**254*1.00g*************
**florida****-wi-a-----**254*1.00g*************
```

Because spaces aren't good delimiters and after reading `man lvs` I found it has several options to print the output, one of them is the `--separator` parameter which allows you to use a personalized separator for each column, I've used a "," (comma) which is common for CSV.

Then, looking for options to delimit `awk` [I've found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383981/how-to-replace-empty-cells-of-a-specific-column) an option to use a field separator on it, I've glued that with the [print formatting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231995/how-to-separate-fields-with-space-or-tab-in-awk) explained here.

I just had to search and read a little but all the answers for this problem were on internet.

Comment: Thanks Miguel Ortiz. But also I need the fields which holds the empty values and sometimes some fields may have values in one row and not in another rows.